# MySql LEFT join multiple table same with same id or name

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

i'm having some problems. with the JEFT JOIN sql statement.
i have 3 tables:

user , products, prod_images.

```
table.user user_id 

table.products user_id item_id

table.prod_images user_id item_id
```

when i run this query to get data that relation, its work fine.
but only work if the prod_images table are not empty. 
when the prod_images empty
the sql right join merge the result and i get null to the products.item_id array

```
 SELECT products.*, prod_images.*, users.*
 FROM products 
 LEFT JOIN prod_images 
    ON products.item_id=prod_images.item_id
    AND prod_images.is_primary = '1'
JOIN users 
    ON users.user_id=products.seller_id 
    WHERE products.status = '1' 
    ORDER BY created DESC
```

How can i make this query work fine when the table.prod_images 
is empty ?

Comment: `products.item_id=products.item_id` this is quite weird.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and expected result?

Comment: reno, my mistake. should be : prod_images.item_id=products.item_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your query is almost ok.

And it returns everything you asked for, but you should avoid of requesting `products.*, prod_images.*, users.*` because it is easy to confuse ourselves.

So if you change this part at least to `SELECT products.item_id PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID, products.*, prod_images.*, users.*`

And one another note, your query probably returns no `products.item_id` not when `prod_images` has no related records (because it `LEFT JOIN`ed) but when `users` has no related records because it is `INNER JOIN`ed. So I would start from changing `JOIN users` to `LEFT JOIN users`.

**PS** Look at @Reno comment. I did not mention that. for sure you should change `ON products.item_id=products.item_id` to `ON products.item_id=prod_images.item_id`

Comment: my query returns like this 
[item_id] =>

Comment: sorry : this is the result
Array
(
    [item_id] => 
 [item_name] => HERO
 [user_id] => 31
 [filename] =>
)

Comment: Alex , when i the query result are the same with left join or join. when there is no prod_images  the products.item_id are just empty beacuse the join merge the the row.

Comment: try to hear what is the problem: when you requesting `products.*, prod_images.*` and you have `item_id` in both tables and later on you try to get  `['item_id']` from your php array, why do you thing that is `product.item_id`  but not `prod_images.item_id`? to be sure you should call only columns you need, so try to use my `SELECT products.item_id PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID` and check `['PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID']` in your php array, I guess you could be surprized.

Comment: thank you Alex , its seem to work. so you mean just work with alias? so when i have alot of column per table i need to write: SELECT products.item_id PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID,products.item_name PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID, and so on. there is no way to shorten it?

Comment: not really, it is not about *alias*ing, that is more about **duplicate** column names you have. so the best practice is to call only columns you need. for example: `SELECT products.item_id, products.name, prod_images.file_path, users.user_id`

Comment: Great! i will do it 
1+ Alex